# Firebug Failed to load given url

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug

Images are loaded on my html pages. But Firebug shows that it failed to load given url when I hover on the element on firebug panel.

[image: Firebug Failed to load given url]

Comment: No idea with additional info, but maybe firebug popup tries to load on the local machine some work folders assets/... Maybe try along this hunt idea or provide more details. Thanks (eg. if there is one succeed ing and one failing request in web server log

Comment: @Dilettant Something wrong with firebug , It is fine when I put it on my local server. But it does not work when opening html file directly , I also tried giving full path of the image , It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

That's obviously a bug in Firebug 2.x. I only found the related [issue #3540](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/3540), so you might want to [file a new issue for it](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/new).

Having said that, Firebug as extension [is going away with one of the upcoming versions of Firefox](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/). It is implemented as theme for the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead, which don't have this issue. So, I suggest to use those instead.